# Correctly typing components when using module federation and lazy/suspense

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, vite, webpack-module-federation

When using module federation and lazy loading how can I type a component to get static type checking?

Simple example is importing a Button into the host app from the remote

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const Button = lazy(() => import('remote/Button'));

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Host app</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Button />
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Adding a remote.d.ts file allows this to work with out any static checking.

```
declare module 'remote/Button' {
    export default Button;
}
```

But this does not allow for any type checking on the Button component as any props can be passed to it as the type is `any`

`const Button: React.LazyExoticComponent<any>`
Is there a way to correctly type the Button as an example trying this

```
declare module 'remote/Button' {
    import { React } from 'react';

    interface ButtonProps {
        label: string;
    }

    const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps>;
    export default Button;
}
```

The Button is now of type

```
const Button: React.LazyExoticComponent<React.FC<ButtonProps>>
```

But I get type errors if I add a label

```
Type '{ label: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
  Property 'label' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes'.
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work and gives the ability to type check the component.

```
import {lazy, Suspense} from 'react';
const Button = lazy(() => import('remote/Button'));

interface ButtonProps {
    label: string;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Host app</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        {(Button as React.FC<ButtonProps>)({ label: 'Click me'})}
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```